# Function can't be called

Tags: python-3.5

When I am running this program, then it is printing "**Calling function"** but the function call after that is not working. When I am calling the function in Idle, then it is working fine. Where is the mistake?

```
def find(word, letter):
    index = 0
    while index < len(word):
        if word[index] == letter:
            return index
        index = index + 1
    return -1

print('Calling function')
find('banana', 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is returning some value.
Try this:

```
def find(word, letter):
    index = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        if word[i] == letter:
            index.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return index

print('Calling function')
print find('banana', 'a')
```

Comment: Can you add parentheses to the print statement? The question is tagged with python-3.5.

Comment: Here you are creating a List(index[]), but why shouldn't it work with string?
The output is not the desired one. print(find('banana', 'a'))



Calling function
[1, 3, 5]